# Is there any way to use redis transaction with Spring data redis reactive?

Tags: spring, kotlin, redis, transactions, reactive

Usual `org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate` have that `multi()` method, which allow to start a transaction and `exec()` to commit.

But `org.springframework.data.redis.core.ReactiveRedisTemplate` does not have that methods.

I searched a lot for an any way on how to use transaction with `spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive` and i found no solutions.

The only way i see it now is manualy create `Lettuce Client` Bean and use it along side Spring implementation. But that is not handy to have 2 separate redis clients.

Does anyone know how to use redis transaction with `spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive`? could you please write a simple example?

Comment: Indeed, so why not using just lettuce? 

Comment: i think maybe i just dont know how to use spring implementation. And i already have a lot of usage with spring wrapper, so it would be not easy move all to Lettuce Client